# Issue when loading LDA function in R

Tags: r, tm

I'm using the text-mining `tm` library for R.

I'm running on R version 3.3.1

I have this code:

```
lda <- LDA(docterm,k = 3,method = 'Gibbs')
lda.topics <- as.matrix(topics(lda))

lda.terms <- as.matrix(terms(lda,5))

topic.terms <- c()
topic.terms[1] <- paste(c(lda.terms[,1],'\n'),collapse = '\n')
topic.terms[2] <- paste(c(lda.terms[,2],'\n'),collapse = '\n')
topic.terms[3] <- paste(c(lda.terms[,3],'\n'),collapse = '\n')

tw.df <- tw.df %>%
    mutate(topico = topic.terms[lda.topics])
```

But every time I try to run it with `source file.r`

It throws me this:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "LDA"
```

I don't get it, the `tm` package is installed.

Has anybody encountered this kind of behaviour before?

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the package loaded via `library(tm)` ?

Comment: Hi, no, just execute source("file.r") I'm new to R btw, forgive me if this is noob as hell

Comment: Just loaded it, it says Loading required package: NLP, but the I try again with 'source', same error tho

Comment: I'm not sure then - if the package is installed and loaded sucessfully, and there is an `LDA` function (remembering that R is case sensitive so lda and LDA are not the same), then it should work.

Comment: I dont think you have lda function in tm package . check this - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/tm.pdf . Maybe you can use the one provided by MASS package

Comment: I am confident this last comment should be the official answer. @Indi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing and using the package 'topicmodels'.

```
install.packages('topicmodels')
```

It should work.